# spidev software CS

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, spi

Im using spidev on a raspberry pi 3 to communicate with 2 spi devices.

One on GPIO8 and one on GPIO16.

Spidev requires a parameter for CS but GPIO16 is not a CS line. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can ya connect two Pis via SPI? I thought we need I2C connection. *I2C allows multiple masters and slaves on the bus. On the other hand SPI can only work with one master device controlling multiple slaves*

Comment: [Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=32513) is an interesting link.

Comment: @Yahya I am not trying to connect two pi's. Just two slaves to one master (pi). One is connect to CS0 and another to a random GPIO pin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by connecting the spi devices to other pins.